# Partially applied constant on left hand side of code equation

Tags: isabelle

I need to use `nat_plus_commute.fold_set_fold_remdups` code equation instead of `Finite_Set.fold_def`:

```
interpretation nat_plus_commute: comp_fun_commute "plus :: nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat"
  by standard auto

declare Finite_Set.fold_def [code del]
declare nat_plus_commute.fold_set_fold_remdups [code]
```

The problem is that the first equation is defined only for `plus` operation and so I get the following warning:

```
Partially applied constant "Groups.plus_class.plus" on left hand side of equation, in theorem:
Finite_Set.fold op + ?y (set ?xs) ≡ fold op + (remdups ?xs) ?y
```

As result the following statement

```
value "Finite_Set.fold plus 0 (set [1::nat, 2])"
```

returns the exception:

```
exception Fail raised (line 29 of "generated code"): Finite_Set.fold
```

Is it possible to use a specialized code equation for specific operations (`plus`) and types (`nat`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure want you want to achieve, but note that *Finite_Set.fold* is a low-level construct of which other operations with practically usable properties can only be derived with considerable effort, cf. theories *src/HOL/Finite_Set.thy* and *src/HOL/Groups_Big.thy* for a rough idea.

For summation on finite sets and lists, there are *sum* and *sum_list* which are already equipped with code equations.