# How to fix "partially applied constant on left hand side of code equation"?

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to define the code equation:

```
datatype t = A | B | C

inductive less_t :: "t ⇒ t ⇒ bool" where
  "less_t A B"
| "less_t B C"

code_pred [show_modes] less_t .

fun less_t_fun :: "t ⇒ t ⇒ bool" where
  "less_t_fun A A = False"
| "less_t_fun A B = True"
| "less_t_fun A C = True"
| "less_t_fun B C = True"
| "less_t_fun B _ = False"
| "less_t_fun C _ = False"

lemma tancl_less_t_code [code]:
  "less_t⇧+⇧+ x y ⟷ less_t_fun x y"
  apply (rule iffI)
  apply (erule tranclp_trans_induct)
  apply (erule less_t.cases; simp)
  apply (metis less_t_fun.elims(2) less_t_fun.simps(3) t.simps(4))
  apply (induct rule: less_t_fun.induct; simp)
  using less_t.intros apply auto
  done

value "less_t A B"
value "less_t_fun A C"
value "less_t⇧+⇧+ A C"
```

And get the following warning:

```
Partially applied constant "less_t" on left hand side of equation, in theorem:
less_t⇧+⇧+ ?x ?y ≡ less_t_fun ?x ?y
```

This question is unrelated to transitive closures. I already received such a warning for different theorems:

- [Partially applied constant on left hand side of code equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46784091/partially-applied-constant-on-left-hand-side-of-code-equation)
- [How to use different code lemmas for different modes of inductive predicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52462965/how-to-use-different-code-lemmas-for-different-modes-of-inductive-predicate)

I just need to understand the meaning of this warning and how to fix it. Maybe I should define a different lemma?

Comment: I don't have the answer, but the warning goes away when `[code]` is removed, so it would seem to have something to do with the code generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the structure of your lemma `tancl_less_t_code` is indeed not suitable as code-equations. Note that the outermost constant in the left-hand side of the equations is the transitive closure predicate `tranclp`. So, this tells the code-generator to use the lemma in order to implement `tranclp`. However, using your lemma one only knows how to implement `tranclp` for one specific predicate, namely `less_t`. Therefore, you get the complaint from Isabelle that your implementation is too specific.

There are at least two workarounds.

First, instead of the declaration `[code]`, you can use `[code unfold]`. Then 
every occurrence of `tranclp less_t x y` will be replaced by `less_t_fun` during the code generation. To make this rule even more applicable, I would then reformulate the lemma to `tranclp less = less_t_fun`, so that even if
`tranclp less_t` is not fully applied, the unfolding can happen.

Second, you can take the symmetric version of your lemma and declare it as
`[simp]`. Then in your implementation you just invoke `less_t_fun` instead of
`tranclp less_t` and in the proofs the simplifier will switch to the latter one.

For more information on `[code]` and `[code_unfold]` have a look into the
documentation of the code generator.

Comment: Thanks! At last I've got it. I thought that `less_t` itself is a partial constant (partially-applied function or something like this). One can also use a `[code_abbrev]` annotation for the symmetric lemma.